# why declaration can not be used together with isolatedModules in typescript?

Tags: typescript

**declaration** is used to generate type file, and **isolatedModules** mean all file should be a separate module. Why do these two options use together?

```
error TS5053: Option 'declaration' cannot be specified with option 'isolatedModules'.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the restriction exists. There's an issue on the TS repo asking about this as well https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29490

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Answer

In the issue that Max Heiber referenced in the comments, Wesley Wigham from the TypeScript team [posted the following answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29490#issuecomment-474947274) (emphasis added):

> The reason is for the same reason you can't use const enums in isolated modules: type information. Since **isolated modules compiles each file individually without the types of the files it depends on, any inferred type we would write to a declaration file would potentially be incorrect**, as their calculation would be missing information from the rest of the compilation. There is a limited subset of declaration emit where no types are inferred in the output which could be supported, however.

In other words, `isolatedModules` does not provide enough type information for the creation of complete and accurate `*.d.ts` declaration files.

#### Suggested Workaround

The issue comments also have a suggested workaround, in which we have one `tsconfig` for compiling with isolated modules, and a second tsconfig for creating declaration files.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "incremental": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
    }
}
```

tsconfig-for-declarations.json

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```